How do I set my fn key toggled(like caps lock) on Mac?
I've been on this thing for days now. I just want to make my fn key(globe key)on Macbook toggle. I've tried several things but didn't worked at all.
I really want to get this thing done and not caring about this anymore.
The closest one I've found is get done with shortcuts app with this bash command
"defaults write -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState -int $((!$(defaults read -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState)))
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u"

and apparently I can't let my fn key assigned by itself alone.
I've also tried with Karabiner and also failed. Even tried scripted .json(I haven't even coded with json at all in my whole life) like this
{

"description": "Press Globe to toggle Fn key behavior",
"manipulators": \[

{"from": { 

"apple_vendor_top_case_key_code": "keyboard_fn" 

},

"to": \[{ "shell_command": "bash -c 'defaults write -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState -int $((!$(defaults read -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState))); /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u'"

 }\],

"type": "basic"

}

\]}

and didn't worked at all.
